# Bluetooth speaker programming

Tags: android

i want to know if it is possible that when you connect to Bluetooth speaker by A2dp you can play your desired sound and other sound not be played like sounds of Sms,notification,...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only possible way is for you to turn off all kinds of notification sounds and reactions on your device, otherwise it will interfere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.does this work is possible with other profiles?

Comment: Hi @afshinnama depends on what device we are talking about, but usually you will have to do the same configuration again for no notifications.